# Unify phone numbers before store in database

Tags: database, validation, phone-number, libphonenumber

**I want to import all the contacts number from user's phone address book and store them in the database but since I want to do some processing on them later, all of the phone numbers should have a unify format.**

I have done some research on the Internet and I find out that there are three major format for phone-numbers: ([source: googlei18n/libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber))

- INTERNATIONAL
- NATIONAL
- E164

Then I export and extract my phone contact numbers but I understand that there are plenty of different format numbers from different countries and carriers.

Here's some example:

```
 0123456789
 0 12-345 6789
 +6012345678
 +27 60 123 4567‬
 09131234567
 +98 (310) 1234567
 00982101234567
```

Based-on google's library, if you want to convert any phone number to a different format, I guess, you have to know which country they're belong to and in my case, every contact belongs to different country.

**Now, my question is what are the steps to prepare and convert all of them to one specific format?**

I need to know the whole concept of this operation but If you want to write code, any programming language is okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These answers use the [python](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers) version of libphonenumber, but AFAIK the rules are the same in other ports.

Converting an arbitrary international number to a unified format is *really* easy...

```
>>> import phonenumbers
>>> x = phonenumbers.parse('+1-904-566-6820')
>>> phonenumbers.is_valid_number(x)
True
>>> phonenumbers.format_number(x, phonenumbers.PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL)
'+1 904-566-6820'
```

And you don't need to know country for international format numbers (it has a '+' at the start).

```
>>> phonenumbers.format_number(phonenumbers.parse('+1-904-566-6820'), phonenumbers.PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL)
'+1 904-566-6820'
>>> phonenumbers.format_number(phonenumbers.parse('+1 (904) 566-6820'), phonenumbers.PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL)
'+1 904-566-6820'
>>> phonenumbers.format_number(phonenumbers.parse('+33 6 10 45 04 89'), phonenumbers.PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL)
'+33 6 10 45 04 89'
```

The only time you need to know a number's country is when the source number is not in valid international format...

```
>>> phonenumbers.format_number(phonenumbers.parse('(904) 566-6820'), phonenumbers.PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home15/jgalloway12/code/wdPhone/phonenumbers/phonenumberutil.py", line 2450, in parse
    "Missing or invalid default region.")
phonenumbers.phonenumberutil.NumberParseException: (0) Missing or invalid default region.
>>> phonenumbers.format_number(phonenumbers.parse('(904) 566-6820', 'US'), phonenumbers.PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL)
'+1 904-566-6820'
```

The country code you pass to `parse` only serves as a fallback in the case that the input number can't be parsed as international.